# What optimizations does std::execution::unseq enable?

Tags: c++

In C++20, another execution policy: `std::execution::unseq` was added.
It means, that an algorithm will be executed on current thread, but without guarantee that operations will be done in the order of the elements.

What is the rationale for adding that to the language, what optimizations does it enable? As far as I looked through implementation, this flag is pretty much treated exactly as `seq`, unless I missed something (what is likely). In my experience, compilers already recognize loops that they can vectorize (for trivial types) and vectorization is possible there without any special flags due to "as-if" rule. So, what does `std::execution::unseq` change?

Comment: Not sure if only for error detection, the documentation mentions things like locks, memory allocation/freeing etc which isn’t allowed to be done here, so that’s one nice thing this brings. You get compilation errors if you try to do those. But you mention “treated exactly as `unseq`”, which unseq is that if it’s not this unseq?

Comment: Sorry, a typo, I meant " treated exactly like `seq` ". 
> You get compilation errors if you try to do those - I don't think you are right there, afaik compilers don't perform any checking, the standard just requires this guarantee.

Comment: Could be, what I read is slightly ambiguous if compilers give an error, or if it’s just a runtime error, or some other way an “error” represents itself. But it would be possible to check for it since it’s not allowed at least

Answer (score 5):

> So, what does std::execution::unseq change?

Standard says (latest draft):

> [execpol.unseq]
>
> The class unsequenced_­policy is an execution policy type used as a unique type to disambiguate parallel algorithm overloading and indicate that a parallel **algorithm's execution may be vectorized**, e.g., executed on a single thread using instructions that operate on multiple data items.
>
> ---
>
> [algorithms.parallel.exec]
>
> The invocations of element access functions in parallel algorithms invoked with an execution policy object of type execution​::​unsequenced_­policy are permitted to execute in an unordered fashion in the calling thread of execution, unsequenced with respect to one another in the calling thread of execution.
>
> [Note 4: This means that multiple function object invocations can be interleaved on a single thread of execution, which overrides the usual guarantee from [intro.execution] that function executions do not overlap with one another.
> — end note]

---

> compilers already recognize loops that they can vectorize

Some compilers may sometimes be smart enough to detect that vectorisation is possible, and guess that it is beneficial. But it isn't simple and won't always work. By telling the compiler that vectorisation is OK and desirable, there won't be guessing involved.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to eerorika answer

Standard says

> During the execution of a parallel algorithm with the execution::unsequenced_policy policy, if the invocation of an element access function exits via an uncaught exception, terminate() shall be called.

This might give the compiler opportunity to optimize your code more aggressively